# Can not type any text in textarea

Tags: reactjs

i can not type any text in my text areas.
I can not modify my default text.

How i can solve my problem ?

```
class SomeClass extends Component{
 constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {data:[]}

        }
handleChange(e, media_id){
        var newState = $.each(this.props.data, function() {
        if (this.media_id  == media_id) {
            this.text = e.target.value  }
        });
        this.setState({data:newState})
     };
 render(){
    return(
        <div className="col s9 m9 cards-container">
        {this.props.data.map(item =>
             <div className="input-field">
               <textarea 
                   placeholder="Описание с тегами" ref="tags" 
                   className="materialize-textarea" value={ item.text }
                   onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, item.media_id)}
               />
            </div>)})}
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the order of your parameters to `handleChange`:

```
handleChange(media_id, e)
```

Because of how the `handleChange` is bound, the parameters are going to be in the reverse order:

```
this.handleChange.bind(this, item.media_id)
```

That returns a partially applied function where `item.media_id` is its first parameter. The eventual `Event` object that is passed when `onChange` happens will be the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

i see you are using *es6* standart , in your `handleChange` :

```
<textarea onChange={...} ...
```

you have to replace with

```
onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, item.media.id)}
```

that's all